# Laravel returning SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'emp_id'

Tags: angular, laravel

Please i am new to laravel, I want to insert form values into database, but i am getting this error.
`"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'emp_id' cannot be null"`.

This is my  laravel code.

```
private function saveEmployeeLeave(Request $request)
{
    
    $empInfo = new AsEmployeeLeave();
    $empInfo->emp_id = $request->emp_id;
    $empInfo->department_id = $request->department;
    $empInfo->application_time =  Carbon::parse($request->application_time)->format('Y-m-d');
    $empInfo->type = $request->selectedLeaveType;
    $empInfo->date_from = $request->date_from;
    $empInfo->date_to = $request->date_to;
    $empInfo->comment = $request->comment;
    $empInfo->requester_emp_id = $request->id;
    $empInfo->requester_sign = $request->english_name;
    $empInfo->approval_emp_id = $request->approval_emp_id;
    $empInfo->approval_sign = $request->manager;
    $empInfo->contact = $request->contact;
    $empInfo->hours = $request->hours;
    $empInfo->status = $request->status;

    $empInfo->save();
    return $empInfo;
}
```

This is my angular code for getting the data.

```
submitLeave(){
        this.leaveList.emp_id= this.empData.id;
        this.leaveList.department_id= this.leaveList.department_id;
        if(!this.leaveList.selectedLeaveType){
            this.snotifyService.error("Please select type of leave");
        }  else if(!this.leaveList.date_from){
            this.snotifyService.error("Please select date from");
        } else if(!this.leaveList.date_to){
            this.snotifyService.error("Please select date to");
        } else{
            this.hrService.createLeave(this.leaveList).subscribe(data => {
            if(data.status_code == 200){
                this.snotifyService.success("leave added successfully");
                this.modalService.dismissAll();
            } else {
                this.snotifyService.error(data.message);    
            }
            },error=>{
                this.snotifyService.error("Not able to load the data. Please reload project and try 
again.");    
            });
        }
    }
```

The data service is returning this data, and it is this data that i want to store in the database with laravel

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "total_records": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "errors": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "employee_id": "ASM1060",
            "department_id": "1",
            "english_name": "francis",
            "manager": "Luis Andres",
            "reports_to": 12,
            "paid_vacation": 15,
            "used_vacation": 0,
            "department": "IT",
            "position_name": "IT Supervisor",
            "status": null,
            "leave_status": "Rejected",
            "leave_eligible": 120,
            "days_eligible": "15 days",
            "remainder_eligible": 0,
            "hours_eligible": 0,
            "leavedays_eligible": "15 days 0 hour(s)",
            "leave_balance": 120,
            "days_balance": "15 days",
            "remainder_balance": 0,
            "hours_balance": 0,
            "leavedays_balance": "15 days 0 hour(s)"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `$request->emp_id` is null , you did not pass it to controller

Answer (score 0):

You pass the employee_id but in the controller you can access the emp_id thats why you laravel show database error
You can fix this simple change the name employee_id to emp_id or vice versa

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Saini, The employee_id and emp_id are two different fields, one is a string and one is an int. so they are different, I passed both so that i can select from the query. I have tried it and it didnt work though

Comment: this.leaveList.emp_id= this.empData.id

Comment: The empData is a value i passed in the local storage to get the ID of the login user, it is different from the employee_id,  i passed it to the emp_id which is part of the leave database field and the employee table.

Comment: It is getting the right data from the API, the problem is how to pass the data to the function in controller to insert data into the database, i tried many things but no progress yet

Comment: I your submitLeave() you cannot have any emp_id value  you pass null value to the controller that why this error occur you can first print the emp_id then check id exist or not